# VB6: Storing and Retrieving Forms in a Collection

Tags: collections, vb6, casting

Getting some weird behavior in VB6 and I'm throwing a net out for some answers.

I have a collection in which I use to store a group of custom forms of the same type.

```
Dim formCollection As New Collection

Public Sub AddForm()
    Dim newForm As New frmCustomForm
    formCollection.Add(newForm)
End Sub
```

Then in another routine I iterate through the collection. But as I cast the variant back into the custom form class I get a type casting error ("Run-time error '13': Type mismatch").

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Dim someForm As frmCustomForm
    Dim iterator As Integer

    For iterator = 1 To formCollection.Count
        Set someForm = formCollection.Item(iterator) ' The error appears here
        someForm.SomeProperty = 3
    Next iterator
End Sub
```

It seems that though initially it was of the custom form class, as it got stored into the collection it lost it's type and can't be casted back. Further, if I put a breakpoint before I try casting the stored form and then I examine the object through Locals, it's lost all the class specific information such as property names, which appear only as 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use parentheses like this in VB6. Try this

```
    formCollection.Add newForm
```

or this

```
    Call formCollection.Add(newForm)
```

In your case parentheses force VB6 to evaluate the default property of the object reference and this gets stored in the collection, not the form reference.

Usually you get an extra space in the IDE just before the opening bracket like this

```
    formCollection.Add (newForm)
```

which should make you extra suspicious.

Comment: Wow, that worked, thanks! That is interesting behavior. So the parentheses aren't always the function argument syntax in VB6? For example, "FunctionFoo (argument)" evaluates argument, but "FunctionFoo(argument1, argument2)" is a wholly different behavior, i.e. the list of arguments for a function.

Comment: And also, the way the compiler analyzes the parenthesis for "FunctionFoo (argument)" is different than "result = FunctionFoo(argument)", correct?

Comment: `(` and `)` must surround the parameters when you're using the return value of the sub/function (call is included here), but they MUST NOT be used when you aren't using the return value. This means that if you put them in, they fall back to the default evaluation that @wqw mentioned.

Comment: `FunctionFoo(argument1, argument2)` is a syntax error. To keep the parentheses you need either `Call` or making it part of expression incl. assignment.

Comment: Correct answer - The brackets force the parameter to be passed ByVal regardless of the ByVal or ByRef keyword in the function definition. So you either need to lose the brackets or use Call for a single argument Method.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Dim someForm As frmCustomForm

    For Each someForm In formCollection
        someForm.SomeProperty = 3
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't work either as I get the same error. The problem either sounds like an error on my end or a more fundamental problem with typing is handled by VB6.

Answer (score 0):

Scripting.Dictionary may help you better than Collection. It is powerful and faster than Collections. You will need to reference scrrun.dll in your Project.